# Appending To an array in MongoDB (PHP 7.2)

Tags: php, json, mongodb, php-7.2

`push()` operation will append the data, I know. But, I'm running into a weird problem. I have a very simple and straightforward PHP script. It get some JSON, based on it, it will look for an entry in MongoDB and then update certain place.

This is my MongoDB JSON :

```
{
  "_id": "5d246a404ddb5c24231eb3f2",
  "series_id": "GY5VKE9EY",
  "episodes": {
    "3x": {
      "My First Title": [
        {
          "offsetLeft": 157,
          "offsetTop": -1,
          "episode_number": "50"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Now, I want to add new entry in `My First Title` key. I have this JSON I want to add.

```
{
  "offsetLeft": 157,
  "offsetTop": -1,
  "episode_number": "50"
}
```

The script I've written, when I give it that JSON, it says that the document was updated. However, it was never updated when I checked in the DB.

Here's my PHP Code :

```
try{

    $encoded_json = json_encode($final_array_to_update);
    $internal_json = array("episodes" => array($key_value => $encoded_json));
    $collection->updateOne(
        array("_id" => $_id),
        array('$push' => $internal_json)
    );
    echo "Updated The Document.";
}
catch (Exception $ex)
{
    echo $ex;
}
```

Also, for some weird reason, now the error changed to :

`BulkWriteException: The field 'episodes' must be an array but is of type object in document`

I'm not sure what the issue is. Can somebody help me out with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB's [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator is used to appends a specified value to an **array**.

According to the docs, $push operators sintax is:

```
{ $push: { <field1>: <value1>, ... } }
```

So, the error message is very clear: you are trying to **$push** something to the subdocument **episodes**, when you actually want to add data to the array **My First Title**.

Try this:

```
$final_array_to_update = [
    'offsetLeft' => 157,
    'offsetTop' => -1,
    'episode_number' => '50'
];   

// index is the path to the array - value is the array to push
$update = [
    'episodes.3x.My First Title' => $final_array_to_update 
];

$collection->update(
    ['_id' => $_id],
    ['$push' => $update]
);
```

Comment: Thanks, the explanation made sense and the code worked. But, I had to use `updateOne()`, instead of `update()`. Thanks again!